# Why this onScroll Java is not working?

Tags: onscroll

I have the following code... But it doesn't effects when I scroll page, it effects everytime the page is opened. What's wrong? It should effect only when the object stay 300px from the top.

```html
<html>
<title>ON SCROLL TEST</title>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/css/animations.css">
<style>
#object{
 background-color: #fe5652;

 visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#object').each(function(){
  var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

  var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (imagePos < topOfWindow+300) {
    $(this).addClass("slideUp");
   }
  });
 });
</script>
<div style="height: 400px"></div>
<div id="object" class="slideUp" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 350px;">
TESTE <br> TESTE <br> TESTE <br> TESTE
</div>
<div style="height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: I've wrote wrong haha Sorry. It's Javascript